# Entity IEnumerable only getting base class - not derived classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have made a base class called `Customer` with two derived classes `PrivateCustomer` and `BusinessCustomer`. 
Here's my Entity model:

[image]

In my view, I need to show a list of *all* customers. But I also want to show if they're a business or private customer, and get some specific information for e.g. a private customer.

My view requires the model `@model IEnumerable<CarDealerMVC.Models.Customer>` and it gets the model from the controller through `return View(db.CustomerSet.ToList());`

However, that list doesn't contain the derived objects - only the base (`Customer`). So while I can check if it's a business or private customer with `@if (item is Models.PrivateCustomer)`, I cannot print a `PrivateCustomer` specific property, e.g. Cpr.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved using `DisplayFor` templates, declaring the `@Model` type for each different concrete element type.

As an example `Shared/DisplayTemplates/PrivateCustomer.cshtml`:

```
@Model PrivateCustomer
@Model.Id
@Model.Name
@Model.Phone
@Model.Cpr
@Model.Genger
```

And `Shared/DisplayTemplates/BusinessCustomer.cshtml`:

As an example `Shared/DisplayTemplates/BusinessCustomer.cshtml`:

```
@Model BusinessCustomer
@Model.Id
@Model.Name
@Model.VatNumber
@Model.Fax
```

Then in your view you need to loop the collection as follows, using reflection to locate the template at runtime:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => item, item.GetType().Name)
}
```

This way abstracts out specific concrete instances but unfortunately means duplication of your common base properties i.e. `Id`, `Name` etc.

Comment: Nice idea, but this means you lose control over which properties are shown (so it would include FK ID fields, etc.), and also *in which order* they're shown. Unless you resort to decorating the model properties with custom attributes, etc.

Comment: @GaryMcGill You have full control over which properties are shown. This uses reflection of the classes' property name to lookup the DisplayFor template which is created manually. Properties order is up to you and the FK won't be rendered.

Comment: This is a good approach. But I would go one step further. I would create view models for each of these types. That can eliminate @GaryMcGill's concern of having unwanted properties etc and also you can add attributes. The other biggest advantage is you can even combine fields and expose them to view as a single property. Ex: Address

Comment: @KosalaW This won't have unwanted properties, it is using reflection to manually render an editor template that you create yourself. You could use ViewModels too though as it's good practice anyway but use the same method.

Comment: @hutchonoid: Yes. I know. It depends on your editor template. However those templates are not deigned by your most experienced developers sometimes. We really do not want to expose sensitive fields to them. Do we? :)

Comment: @KosalaW I'm not aware of who you would have develop your editor templates. I think this might be outside the scope of the question. :)

Comment: @hutchonoid: Sorry, I *completely* misunderstood your answer. For some reason I thought that you were iterating over the properties of the model using reflection. I think this was a case of seeing what I expected to see, rather than actually paying attention. Now that I look again, it's a nice solution.

Comment: @GaryMcGill No problem, I knew what you meant. I think other's think the same too. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

By casting to the appropriate type.

For example:

```
@foreach (var customer in Model)
{
    var businessCustomer = customer as Models.BusinessCustomer;
    if (businessCustomer != null)
    {
        @businessCustomer.VatNumber
    }

    var privateCustomer = customer as Models.PrivateCustomer;
    if (privateCustomer != null)
    {
        @privateCustomer.Cpr
    }
}
```

Comment: @Henk if not in the view, what model type (and with which properties)  are you going to send to the view? I like Hutch's approach more though.